# ¿Que es mas eficiente una matriz o un vector en C?

Tags: c

Quisiera saber cual de los dos es mas eficiente en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución (no importa si consume mas recursos que otros).
Dicha comparación es en base a lo siguiente:

```
Acceder de forma matriz[fila][columna];
Acceder de forma vector[totalcolumnas * fila + columna];
```

O si existe otro mejor método.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Caso 1: acceso aleatorio**

Vamos a comprobar qué sucede con un caso práctico sencillo:

```
int matrizPila[10][10];
int **matrizDinamica;
int vectorPila[100];
int* vectorDinamico;

int funcMatrizPila(int fila, int columna)
{
  return matrizPila[fila][columna];
}

int funcMatrizDinamica(int fila, int columna)
{
  return matrizDinamica[fila][columna];
}

int funcVectorPila(int fila, int columna)
{
  return vectorPila[fila*10+columna];
}

int funcVectorDinamico(int fila, int columna, int numColumnas)
{
  return vectorDinamico[fila*numColumnas+columna];
}
```

Las variables las he etiquetado como `extern` para evitar warnings al compilar.

Compilándo el código anterior con gcc 6.3 (es una compilación C++ aunque no creo que diste mucho de una compilación en C) el resultado es el siguiente:

```
funcMatrizPila(int, int):
    movsx   rdi, edi
    movsx   rsi, esi
    lea     rax, [rdi+rdi*4]
    lea     rax, [rsi+rax*2]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR matrizPila[0+rax*4]
    ret
funcMatrizDinamica(int, int):
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR matrizDinamica[rip]
    movsx   rdi, edi
    movsx   rsi, esi
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+rdi*8]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+rsi*4]
    ret
funcVectorPila(int, int):
    lea     eax, [rdi+rdi*4]
    lea     eax, [rsi+rax*2]
    cdqe
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR vectorPila[0+rax*4]
    ret
funcVectorDinamico(int, int, int):
    imul    edi, edx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR vectorDinamico[rip]
    lea     edx, [rdi+rsi]
    movsx   rdx, edx
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+rdx*4]
    ret
```

Si analizamos el código resultante podemos sacar algunas conclusiones:

- En el caso de `matrizPila` y `vectorPila` el resultado es prácticamente el mismo. Esto es porque en ambos casos la memoria es contigua y está organizada de la misma forma, luego la operación que permite obtener el valor de una celda es la misma.
- En el caso de `matrizDinamica` el compilador tiene que resolver dos indirecciones para obtener el valor (uno para saltar a la fila que corresponda y otro para saltar a la columna para la fila dada). Esto se traduce en un rendimiento más pobre respecto a los dos casos anteriores.
- En el caso de `vectorDinamico`, el compilador se ve obligado a realizar una indirección más respecto a `vectorPila`. Esto se traduce, como en el caso anterior, en un rendimiento inferior. Además ahora tiene que realizar un producto de forma manual (`fila*numColumnas` -> `imul edi,edx`), lo que supone una penalización importante.

Un detalle que no se ve en el ensamblador pero que también afecta es la localidad de los datos. Los ordenadores tienden a cachear la memoria para permitir un acceso rápido a los datos. Esto tiende a acelerar muchísimo las operaciones si los datos tienden a estar todos juntos. En el caso de `matrizDinamica` este punto no se cumple ya que cada fila se encontrará en una posición aleatoria de la memoria y esto obligará al sistema a repaginar la caché constantemente y esto se puede traducir fácilmente en una pérdida de rendimiento bastante perceptible.

**Caso 2: acceso a posiciones conocidas en tiempo de compilación**

```
int matrizPila[10][10];
int **matrizDinamica;
int vectorPila[100];
int* vectorDinamico;

int funcMatrizPila()
{
  return matrizPila[3][4];
}

int funcMatrizDinamica()
{
  return matrizDinamica[3][4];
}

int funcVectorPila()
{
  return vectorPila[3*10+4];
}

int funcVectorDinamico(int numColumnas)
{
  return vectorDinamico[3*numColumnas+4];
}
```

Para este código el ensamblador resultante es:

```
funcMatrizPila():
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR matrizPila[rip+136]
    ret
funcMatrizDinamica():
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR matrizDinamica[rip]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+24]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+16]
    ret
funcVectorPila():
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR vectorPila[rip+136]
    ret
funcVectorDinamico(int):
    lea     eax, [rdi+rdi*2]
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR vectorDinamico[rip]
    cdqe
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+16+rax*4]
    ret
```

En este caso observamos lo siguiente:

- El acceso a `matrizPila` y a `vectorPila` es exactamente el mismo y el tiempo de ejecución tiende a 0. El compilador es capaz de precalcular el offset del salto, reduciendo la obtención del resultado a resolver una simple suma.
- El acceso a `matrizDinamica` y `vectorDinamico` es más sencillo, lo que debería implicar un menor tiempo de ejecución. Quizás el mayor efecto se consigue en el caso de `vectorDinamico`, pero lo más costoso que es resolver las dos indirecciones las tiene que seguir realizando.

Vistas así las cosas la clasificación, en este caso, será muy similar a la del caso 1 pero con tiempos de ejecución más bajos.

**Caso práctico:**

Vamos a probar ahora todos los casos que hemos visto para ver como se comportan. Para ello podemos usar un código como el siguiente:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matrizPila[10][10];
int **matrizDinamica;
int vectorPila[100];
int* vectorDinamico;

int funcMatrizPila(int fila, int columna)
{
  return matrizPila[fila][columna];
}

int funcMatrizDinamica(int fila, int columna)
{
  return matrizDinamica[fila][columna];
}

int funcVectorPila(int fila, int columna)
{
  return vectorPila[fila*10+columna];
}

int funcVectorDinamico(int fila, int columna, int numColumnas)
{
  return vectorDinamico[fila*numColumnas+columna];
}

int funcMatrizPilaFijo()
{
  return matrizPila[3][4];
}

int funcMatrizDinamicaFijo()
{
  return matrizDinamica[3][4];
}

int funcVectorPilaFijo()
{
  return vectorPila[3*10+4];
}

int funcVectorDinamicoFijo(int numColumnas)
{
  return vectorDinamico[3*numColumnas+4];
}

int res = 0;

#define BEGIN_TEST \
clock_t begin = clock(); \
for( int i=0; i<10000000; i++) \
  for( int j=0; j<100; j++)

#define END_TEST(nombre) \
clock_t end = clock(); \
double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; \
printf("%-22s: %f\n",nombre,time_spent);

void testFunc0( const char* funcName, int(*func)())
{
  BEGIN_TEST

  res += func();

  END_TEST(funcName)
}

void testFunc1( const char* funcName, int(*func)(int), int var1)
{
  BEGIN_TEST

  res += func(var1);

  END_TEST(funcName)
}

void testFunc2( const char* funcName, int(*func)(int, int), int var1, int var2)
{
  BEGIN_TEST

  res += func(var1,var2);

  END_TEST(funcName)
}

void testFunc3( const char* funcName, int(*func)(int, int, int), int var1, int var2, int var3)
{
  BEGIN_TEST

  res += func(var1,var2,var3);

  END_TEST(funcName)
}

int main()
{
  matrizDinamica = (int**)malloc(10*sizeof(int*));
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    matrizDinamica[i] = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));

  vectorDinamico = (int*)malloc(100*sizeof(int));

  testFunc0( "funcMatrizPilaFijo",    funcMatrizPilaFijo);
  testFunc0( "funcVectorPilaFijo",    funcVectorPilaFijo);
  testFunc0( "funcMatrizDinamicaFijo",funcMatrizDinamicaFijo);
  testFunc1( "funcVectorDinamicoFijo",funcVectorDinamicoFijo,10);
  testFunc2( "funcMatrizPila",        funcMatrizPila,3,4);
  testFunc2( "funcVectorPila",        funcVectorPila,3,4);
  testFunc2( "funcMatrizDinamica",    funcMatrizDinamica,3,4);
  testFunc3( "funcVectorDinamico",    funcVectorDinamico,3,4,10);
}
```

En mi caso los resultados obtenidos son los siguientes:

```
funcMatrizPilaFijo    : 1.810000
funcVectorPilaFijo    : 1.800000
funcMatrizDinamicaFijo: 1.800000
funcVectorDinamicoFijo: 2.092000
funcMatrizPila        : 2.161000
funcVectorPila        : 2.190000
funcMatrizDinamica    : 2.321000
funcVectorDinamico    : 2.940000
```

Ahí vemos como efectivamente acceder a posiciones conocidas en tiempo de compilación supone una mejora de tiempo (en torno a un 10%-20%).

Un resultado que parece contradecir lo que he comentado es que los tiempos de acceso de `vectorDinamico` son peores que los obtenidos para `matrizDinamica`. Esto es así porque en este ejemplo tan sencillo la memoria de la matriz no solo tiene muchas posibilidades de acabar en posiciones consecutivas sino que además debido a su poco tamaño (400 bytes), no debería presentar demasiados problemas para la paginación de la caché. En entornos más complejos el resultado de `matrizDinamica` debería ser bastante peor.

Comment: No tengo palabras. Impecable.  *Peaso* de respuesta, que decimos en mi tierra.

Comment: @Trauma gracias :). Yo creo que tu respuesta es compatible con la mía, deberías plantearte el restaurarla